# Speed up large database queries

Tags: mysql, performance, index, innodb, partitioning

I am running a large local database with MySQL and InnoDB. The size is around 30GB for data and 6GB for Keys. The machine has 16GB of RAM.

The table looks like this

```
symbol VARCHAR(10),
iso_datestamp VARCHAR(14),
-- a lot more columns with values with mostly DECIMAL(26,6)s
```

I have BTREE indexes on the symbol and the iso_datestamp.

The operations I run are mostly updates which are run like this:

1. `DELETE FROM table WHERE symbol = 'XXX'`
2. `INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES (...)`

This needs to be done to avoid data inconsistencies as opposed to just appending data.

I also frequently run analysis as in
`SELECT FROM table WHERE symbol in ('XXX', 'YYY', ...) [AND iso_datestamp > '2015...']`

Per symbol I have around 3000 entries.

**The performance problem**: As soon as the table starts to grow over around 10GB, the `DELETE` and `INSERT` statements slow down substantially from usually less than 0.4 seconds to well over 1 second even up to 5 seconds and more as the table keeps growing. RAM is not limiting (according to `top`).

I need the total of `DELETE` and `INSERT` to be around 1 second on average (of course faster is also fine)...

I am having 2 ideas right now:

- Using hash indexes instead of btree indexes, since I am only doing equality operation
- Partitioning the table using the symbol and the range

Are those viable strategies? Do both, just one? Other things I should do to improve the speed?

Comment: Does the Plan change? Is IO throughput a bottleneck?

Answer (score 2):

- `iso_datestamp` to a MySQL `TIMESTAMP` so that it can be 5 bytes instead of 15.
- Use InnoDB, not MyISAM.  (This is critical to some of the items below.)
- Use `CHARACTER SET ascii` (or `latin1`) unless you need the multibyte utf8/utf8mb4.
- `PRIMARY KEY(symbol, datestamp)`
- An auto_increment is a waste of space and indexing.  The above is a 'natural PK' *and* it provides an efficient index.
- `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(datestamp))` -- this will significantly speed up deletion of 'old' rows.
- With that PK and partitioning, you may not need any secondary indexes, thereby completely eliminating the 6GB you mentioned.  (If you have queries that are not adequately handled, let me know.)
- Shoot for no more than about 50 partitions; do not bother with subpartitions.  (See link below)
- Use `DROP PARTITION` for very efficient deleting by date.  (See link below)  If you are deleting by symbol, let me know.
- `DECIMAL(26,6)` takes 12 bytes.  Consider shrinking it and/or moving to an 8-byte `DOUBLE`.  Caution: Double's ~16 significant digits and binary format may lead to rounding issues.
- Consider using a 3-byte `MEDIUMINT INT` for a `symbol_id` and normalize the actual `symbol` name into another (small) table.
- Metrics (eg, "alpha") should probably be 4-byte `FLOATs`.  It's 7 significant digits is overkill for such.
- Set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of *available* memory (after accounting for apps, web server, etc.)
- Insert new data in batches of 100-1000.  This runs literally 10 times as fast as one row at a time.

These changes should help with your various issues.

Currently, performance is falling off a cliff for multiple reasons.  The above tips will delay the cliff for about twice as long, *and* make the cliff less steep.  In some cases, the cliff is eliminated.

Also, my tips will cut back on the I/O needed -- by clustering, by locality of reference, by better caching, etc.

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: Increasing the inno_db_buffer_pool_size from 128MB to 6GB made all the difference. Now I am at around 0.1s per total transaction (~5000 DELETES and 5000 INSERTS).

Answer (score 0):

DELETEs serialize quite badly. You can mitigate that for your use case by partitioning the table by hash of symbol. This will allow you to achieve a much better concurrency on those DELETEs.

For INSERTs the things that might help are:

1. Set transaction isolation level to read-committed
2. Make sure you have enough (innodb_log_file_size x innodb_log_files_in_group). Those should multiply out to the amount required to soak your peak hour of writes.
3. Depending on whether you have an auto_increment column on your tables innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2 will help at high concurrency.
4. Make sure your innodb_io_capacity_max is set to what your storage stack can deliver with 16KB IOPS.

Putting your MySQL data directory on [ZFS with optimal tuning will increase your write performance](https://shatteredsilicon.net/blog/2020/06/05/mysql-mariadb-innodb-on-zfs/).

Also, make sure your innodb_buffer_pool_size is set appropriately (rule of thumb is 50-80% of RAM, depending on how much RAM you have). Your hottest indexes and primary keys should fit into RAM. In your case, 12GB seems like a reasonable amount if it is a dedicated database server.

Comment: Increasing the inno_db_buffer_pool_size from 128MB to 6GB made all the difference. Now I am at around 0.1s per total transaction (~5000 DELETES and 5000 INSERTS).

Comment: Glad I could help. :-)